# BitmapFactory.decodeFile is null unless I WAIT to accept photo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have this weird problem that seems to only happen on one of my tablets that runs android 6.

I have this chunk of code to add a photo taken from the camera to a `recycler view`

1) I create a file object onto device (this is the photo)

2) I get the `uri` from that file

3) I create an intent passing in that `uri` as such

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
// this is done in a fragment, everything else below is in the if statement

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(take_photo_intent, option_int);
```

I know `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` does NOT return anything to `onActivityResult`, but instead writes to the `uri` you pass in.

now inside of `onActivityResult` I have

```
Log.i("PHOTO", "path--->" + uri.getPath());
```

So I want to mention, when the program works or **DOESN'T** work, the `uri` **ALWAYS** has a path, one example of one of the paths is

> /storage/emulated/0/data/20161212_175150797715155.jpg

so to continue on in the `onActivityResult`

5) create bitmap based on `uri` path to use it later on

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
*************** problem here ****************         
Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
```

the temp bitmap returns null **SOME** of the time, let me explain

when I take the photo, the asus android 6 tablet shows two buttons when you take the photo, one button to discard the photo, another to keep the photo.. here is the weird part, ON THAT screen, if I wait like 5-15 seconds before pressing the button to keep the photo, the `bitmap` will NOT be null, but if I take a photo and immediately accept it, the a bitmap is null.

now as said before, does not matter how i do it, if the `bitmap` comes out null, or it does not come out null, it always has a path before passing it into the `bitmapdecode` function (which is weird)

I have no clue if it is the camera software, the physical camera hardware, an android 6 bug....

I also want to say, I am not sure if this is the best code but it has worked on 4 other android devices ( phones, tablets) it is just this ONE tablet that is a asus and only one with android 6, it works fine with everything else

**EDIT:**

I tried this as suggested

```
  Bitmap TEMP = null;
  try {
      TEMP = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

with no luck

**EDIT 2:**

> ```
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
>         BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>         bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
>         Bitmap TEMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
>         Bitmap bitmap_image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(TEMP, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
>
>         if (bitmap_image == null)
>             Log.i("PHOTO", "BITMAP THUMBNAIL NULL");
>
>         setAdapterBitmap(bitmap_image, uri.getPath(), 1);
>     }
> }
> ```

**SOLUTION:**

I had this method to create a `File` object and turn it into a `URI` Object

```
private File createFileForImage() throws IOException {
        String file_creation_time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String image_file_name = DIR_NAME + "_" +  file_creation_time;
        File storage_dir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()), DIR_NAME);
        if (!storage_dir.exists())
        {
            if(!storage_dir.mkdir())
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return File.createTempFile(image_file_name, ".jpg", storage_dir);
    }
```

then I used this after it was return

```
uri = Uri.fromFile(image_file);
```

but for some reason this was working but it had a slight delay that cause bizarre behavior as stated in the original post

Jan Kaufmann suggestion seem to work, to i made some small modifications

```
private Uri getOutputMediaUriFromFile()
{
    File photo_storage_dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), DIR_NAME);
if (!photo_storage_dir.exists())
{
    if (!photo_storage_dir.mkdirs())
    {
        return null;
    }
}

String file_creation_time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String image_file_name = "ipr" + "_" +  file_creation_time;
File photo = new File(photo_storage_dir.getPath() + File.separator + image_file_name + ".jpg");
return Uri.fromFile(photo);
}
```

It does essentially the same thing, but for some reason this doesn't cause the issue I was having, at least not with my testing.

I am glad this now works but can anyone explain why this worked?

Comment: tried `ContentResolver#openInputStream`?

Comment: @pskink can you explain more please?

Comment: try `BitmapFactory#decodeStream` with `ContentResolver#openInputStream` and see if it makes any difference

Comment: no difference :( @pskink

Comment: hmm, try for testing to use `FileObserver` on that file, what events are you getting?

Comment: can you post onActivityResult() method

Comment: I think here is your problem,  ARGB_8888 because , it consumes, each pixel 4 bytes. it gives best color quality image with maximum size of an image.

Comment: Could it be that the photo has a huge size..Try resizing the bitmap. normally anything larger than 2mb will take a few seconds to decode

Comment: @pskink i never used that class before, i would have to look up how before posting back on it

Comment: @Ahamed my onActivityResult, is huge due to other code and not sure how much I can post since this is for a work project, but lets try the ARGB_8888 thing first, do you have another suggestion for this ?

Comment: @Bmbariah thank you for the input, ill see what I can do, i was told there should be no resizing due to the photo information will less exif info if compressed or resized, i know there is ways to save it but it adds more work to what I was told to do so ill look into it and test it out to find out of this is what it is happening =]

Comment: @Ahamed I tried changing the ARGB thing and no luck

Comment: Upon you given code i dont have any suggestion. thats why i requested you to post the onActivityResult() method.without seeing that method we cannot give suggestion to you guys. you can post it. we only see your code. we dont know your project name or package name. no worries.

Comment: @Ahamed I added it =], i erased the log commands and comments and a few null checks but this is basically what is happening

Comment: try instead of uri.getPath() use data.getData(). it will return Uri. then get the path from that Uri.

Comment: @Ahamed that wont work, I guess when you use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT the data parameter is null and the data is saved on the uri that i passed in, i read it in another stackoverflow page and also found out the hard way, i dont remember why we did it this way, using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT but i remember with other parts of our code, we had too. I mean if we have to change it, and modify other parts ofthe code that make take a while but if I have to, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure the image size is not too big. If needed,subsample the original image to save memory

  ```
       BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       opt.inSampleSize = 8;
  ```
- Make sure you have permission for

  ```
     <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Or try constructing your URI into something like this:

`Uri uri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, "myimage");` where *getOutputMediaFileUri* is :

```
 private File getOutputMediaFile(int type, String imgname) {
          // External sdcard location
          //public static String DIRECTORY_PICTURES = "Pictures";
          File mediaStorageDir = new File(
          Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

      // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
      if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
         if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
         }
      }


      File mediaFile;
      if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
         mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + imgname + ".jpg");
      }  else {
         return null;
      }
      return mediaFile;
   }
```

Comment: The function header doesn't match the function (name and return type) is there information missing?

Comment: Actually, scratch that , I used this modified some things and I think it works! ill test more and get back to you

Comment: I believe this fixed it, not sure how but it is not messing up anymore, thanks!

Comment: Ya, I encountered this kind of problem many times in the past, but that's my best try, I shared to you, especially china manufactured phones, man .. it takes a lot hack :D

Comment: well it works and very thankful for it , do you know why this fixed it?

Comment: You're welcome.., It actually fails in the decoding process just like the documentation says *"BitmapFactory.decodeFile = decode a file path into a bitmap. If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null."*, Especially in the case of malformed uri.  As devices's directory structure may vary, it's recommended to access it via Environment object. But again, decoding failure can be also caused by some other things, such the hardware. Ok that's all I know, see you & take care. :)

Comment: that makes sense, once again, thanks, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude:

TEMP = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), YOUR_URL);

If this is not work, I guess that you didn't create a temp file to save the image.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                GEY_FILE;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.i(TAG, "run: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }, 15000);
```

Comment: No luck, I still have to wait about 5-15 seconds then the file appears, other then that it is null. when I create the file before gettings its uri, i do null checks not shown in original post, so not sure whats wrong =[

Comment: I don't think you need to wait for the file.

Comment: If so, you may try using handler. Like:
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    GEY_FILE;
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }, 15000);

Comment: No luck on this =[